# InvalidOperationException when assigning text to a TextField

Tags: c#, wpf

I am having a weird problem with C#, I can't yet explain. I actually planned to create a simple file viewer that automatically updates the displayed text as soon as the file is changed, but it turns out more complicated than I thought.

I have the following basic code:

```
public partial class Main : Window
{
    private FileSystemWatcher watcher;
    private String filePath = "C:\\";
    private String fileName = "example.txt";

    public Main()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.txtFile.Text = File.ReadAllText(filePath + fileName);

        this.watcher = new FileSystemWatcher(filePath);
        this.watcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(watcher_Changed);
        this.watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastAccess | NotifyFilters.LastWrite;
        this.watcher.Filter = fileName;
        this.watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    }

    void watcher_Changed(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        String text = File.ReadAllText(e.FullPath);
        this.txtFile.Text = text; // <-- here comes the exception (line 42)
    }
}
```

Now the assignment to the (WPF) TextField in the changed handler raises a `System.InvalidOperationException` exception, telling me that the object is already used in a different thread. So why do I get that exception and more importantly, what do I have to do, to make this working?

#### edit

By the way, I get the exception regardless of the string I'm assigning.

#### edit2

Full text of the exception, but in german:

```
System.InvalidOperationException wurde nicht behandelt.
  Message="Der aufrufende Thread kann nicht auf dieses Objekt zugreifen, da sich das Objekt im Besitz eines anderen Threads befindet."
  Source="WindowsBase"
  StackTrace:
       bei System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.VerifyAccess()
       bei System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValue(DependencyProperty dp, Object value)
       bei System.Windows.Controls.TextBox.set_Text(String value)
       bei LiveTextViewer.Main.watcher_Changed(Object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e) in ...\Main.xaml.cs:Zeile 42.
       bei System.IO.FileSystemWatcher.CompletionStatusChanged(UInt32 errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* overlappedPointer)
       bei System.Threading._IOCompletionCallback.PerformIOCompletionCallback(UInt32 errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* pOVERLAP)
  InnerException:
```

Comment: You can't assign the Text property of a UI object from a separate thread, at least not directly.  I'll avoid answering because the method I'd recommend is pre-WPF, but I'm sure you'll get an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

FileSystemWatcher is raising this event on a different thread.  You can't access user interface elements from a different thread than the one on which it was created.

You'll need to use the Dispatcher to push the call that sets the text back onto the UI thread:

```
void watcher_Changed(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
    String text = File.ReadAllText(e.FullPath);

    this.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, new Action(() => 
        {
             this.txtFile.Text = text;
             // Do all UI related work here...
        }));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer; maybe it's just me (or another missing import? Which would at least explain all the missing IntelliSense details for Invoke), but this doesn't work: It says that the lambda expression can't be converted into System.Delegate.

Comment: @poke: Sorry - I forgot to put the cast to (Action) in place.  Dispatcher.Invoke takes "System.Delegate",so you have to specify some concrete delegate type.  The above should work now.

Comment: After putting another pair of parentheses around the lambda it indeed compiles and works, and also makes completely sense. Thank you very much :)

Comment: Now that .NET 4 has been out for a bit, I think it's time to start gently pushing people towards `Task` and away from `Dispatcher` and `ISynchronizeInvoke`. I recently [wrote a blog post](http://nitoprograms.blogspot.com/2010/06/reporting-progress-from-tasks.html) on the subject (which uses a nested `Task` to update the UI). What do you think?

Comment: @Stephen: I would agree, in most cases - however, in order to use a Task here, you'd have to store a copy of a task scheduler or the synchronization context in the class.  Otherwise, the code above would need to be refactored to use a lambda for the handler (which just changes the burden of storage to the compiler).  I very much prefer using Tasks for new development, but it's not always as easy to interface with legacy components, especially ones already using callbacks or events.